# Искажение и рябь текстур куба вдали

Tags: c++, opengl

При вращении или отдалении куба от камеры его текстура начинает очень сильно искажаться

**Загрузчик текстуры:**

```
Texture::Texture(string path)
{
texture = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &width, &height, nullptr, STBI_rgb_alpha);

glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, 16);


glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture);


glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //создание мипмапа
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

}

**Фрагментный шейдер:**

```
  uniform sampler2D texture;
  varying vec2 texCoord;
  varying vec3 Normal;
  varying vec4 vertPos;
  uniform vec3 lightPos;
  void main()
  {
  vec3 lightRay = lightPos - vec3(vertPos.xyz);
  lightRay = normalize(lightRay);
  float bn = dot(lightRay, Normal);
  if(bn < 0.5) {bn = 0.5;}
  if(bn > 1) {bn = 1;}

  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texCoord.xy);
  gl_FragColor *= vec4(bn, bn, bn,1);

  }
```

**Вершинный шейдер:**

```
  attribute vec2 textureCoord;
  attribute vec3 normal;
  varying vec2 texCoord;
  varying vec3 Normal;
  uniform mat4 mMatrix;

  varying vec4 vertPos;
  void main()
  {
  Normal = normalize(normal);
  texCoord = textureCoord.xy;
  //gl_Position = vertPos = mMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
  gl_Position = vertPos = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
  }
```

[image: появление зигзагов при развороте куба]

[image: появление полосок на текстуре]

Comment: Ну совсем от этого не избавиться, однако можно попробовать поставить фильтр получше, чем nearest. Например `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.

Comment: Уже пробовал, но не помогло. На самом деле, с проблемой на первой картинке легко смириться, а вот на второй уже слишком сильное отклонение от того, что я хотел бы увидеть... Не знаете ли, как бы это выглядело в Minecraft? Пишу что-то такое же, но с текстурами 32x32, потому что песочница даёт большие возможности для обучения геймдеву

Comment: ¿А как выглядит картинка с другим фильтром? По идее проблема со второй картинки должна была быть ликвидирована. А количество муара на первой - уменьшено.